# Symfony 5 how to automatically send the current user in an update with a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, symfony5

I want my current user to enroll in a rate.

````
```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="matters")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Note", mappedBy="matter")
 */
private $notes;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="studentsMatters")
 */
private $student;
```
````

When he presses "update", the ManyToMany relationship must send the current user.
In my controller, I am trying to send the current user

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="student_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function edit(Request $request, Matter $matter): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(StudentType::class, $matter);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $matter->setStudent($this->getUser());

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('student_index');
    }

    return $this->render('student/edit.html.twig', [
        'matter' => $matter,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

but it doesn't works.

How I do to get current user?

Comment: you already do all neccessary things. are you sure this route is under a firewall protected route? you can also check the "Blameable" Doctrine Extension - which does such things automaticly. https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to update data (you did it). When a form is submitted and valid, , you have to save updates with entity manager or with a service manager before flushing updates.

With entity manager, you only have to add this line juste before to flush data:

```php
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($matter);
```

I'm not sure to understand the last question "how do I get current user?"
Current user was already retrieved by: `$this->getUser();`

Comment: It doesn't works. In fact, for the currentUser, I want that when the user sends the update, its automatically sends the current user like for example a dateTime

Comment: you will have to set the current user somehow and somewhere into your entity. You could write a service class that delivers a new instance of your entity with the current user already set. Then in your controller start with something like $matter = $matterService->getNewInstance();